# How to get all lines between the one containing a certain string and another one containing another string PLUS the line before

Tags: awk

I've spent some time searching the web, but didn't find the answer.
Let's say I have a file containing the following lines :

```
aaaaaaa
vvvvv
ggggg
yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
ssssssssssss
zzzzz
hhhhhhhh
```

I know how to find all lines from the one containing "ffffff" to the one containing "uuuuu" using awk :

```
awk '/ffffff/,/uuuuu/' file
```

But how can I get also the line preceding the first one I found (i.e. "yyyyyyyyy")? Is there something like grep -B 1 to do this?
What I want to get is :

```
yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of the answers you're getting will print text from fffff til the end of the file if uuuuu doesn't exist in the input - is that correct behavior? Some will print if just uuuuu exists with no preceding ffffff - is that correct? Also how should nested and/or overlapping delimiters be handled?

Comment: Those are good questions. I didn't think of it, assuming my file was correct, i.e. there's always the first string and the second one… but you're right, assuming it will always be correct is probably not a good idea…

Comment: It's always trivial to print the text you want and much harder to not print text you don't want in the non-sunny-day cases. Another issue with some of the answers is that if `ffffff` appears as the first line of input they'll print a blank line before the ffffff->uuuuu text - is that desired behavior?

Comment: I'm quite sure ffffff will never be on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a slight variation

```
$ awk '/fffff/{print p; f=1} f; /uuuuu/{f=0} {p=$0}' file

yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
```

assumes begin/end markers don't overlap but can exist multiple times.

**Explanation:** Starting first `fffff` it will print the previous line (captured in p) and sets a flag.  `f;` means print the current line if flag is set, shorthand for `f==1{print $0}`.  Next statement resets the flag if `uuuuu` seen and finally we capture the line to be used in the first statement; this seems unnecessary all except one case it's used but most likely cheaper than comparing each time.

Note that this is probably the simplest script you can get with limited functionality to handle edge cases (multiple begin/end markers, no end marker etc).

Comment: `!f && /ffffff/` fixes unmatched occurrences I think

Comment: This works perfectly fine in my case, but [I don't understand it](https://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2010/6/3/a-day-in-the-life-of-a-coder-part-8.html)… So I need to read the manual to understand… Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Stantheman this is one of the answers that will print from the first `fffff` to the end of the file if `uuuuu` isn't present - is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @Ed Morton Not really. But I'm not sure what would be the best behavior in this case. Copying all lines until the end of file would not be what I want, because my goal is to get the useful data from a 500M log into a ~250k file. But in other hand, it would generate a partial backup of the original log file (which will be erased)…

Comment: You could always set/use the exit status from the awk script based on whether or not the data was in the format you expect to decide if you should make a copy of the original file or not.

Answer (score 3):

To only print if both ffffff and uuuuu exist in the input and not print a blank line if ffffff is the first line in the input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/ffffff/ { f = 1 }
f {
    rec = rec $0 ORS
    if ( /uuuuu/ ) {
        printf "%s", rec
        f = 0
    }
    next
}
{ rec = $0 ORS }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
```

Comment: This doesn't get any result in my case, but it may be because I'm testing it in Cygwin… I'll try in Linux. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with cygwin. I was using cygwin myself when I wrote and tested that in fact. If it doesn't work for you then either you copy/pasted incorrectly or the data you're running it on doesn't look like the data in your question (e.g. maybe you don't have `uuuuu` present). If you run the script I posted on the sample input you posted it **will** produce the expected output you posted.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I made a typo. Your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '/ffffff/ {flag=1; prev=p} flag {if (prev!="") print prev; prev=""; print} /uuuuu/ {flag=0} {p=$0}' file

yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` using the loop `for`:

```
awk -v OFS='\n'  '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "ffffff"|| $i == "uuuuu") print p,$0} {p=$0}' file
yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
```

- or without `for` if there is only one field:

```
awk -v OFS='\n'  '{ if ($1 == "ffffff" || $1 == "uuuuu") print p,$0} {p=$0}' file
yyyyyyyyy
ffffff
rrrrrrrr
uuuuu
```